# Aw snap error on large file uploads

Tags: php, google-chrome, file-upload

I have file uploads on my site, these work fine, but for some reason larger files ( anything over 1GB really ) in chrome gives Aw Snap error, this does not happen in any other browser.

Ive tried looking into it and cant find any information as to a work around on this error. Does anyone know how I can overcome this issue?

Is this something I can sort out on my server to stop the error, the only thing ive been able to find is re-fresh your browser to fix the issue.

Thanks for any support

Answer (score 0):

update your [[image]google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browser..
and increase these values in [php.ini](/questions/tagged/php.ini) file

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 210M
max_execution_time = 500
max_input_time = 500
default_socket_timeout = 500
```

and if you can't access the [php.ini](/questions/tagged/php.ini) file, you can edit these values using [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) file, by

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10800
php_value max_input_time         10800
php_value max_execution_time     10800
php_value upload_max_filesize    200M
php_value post_max_size          210M
php_value memory_limit           500M
```

and give it a try.. it worked for me

I know it's too late answer, but hope it could help you if you still have the same issue, or it could anyone facing the same problem